# Which retrieval mode should be used to count the values which set to zero

Tags: sql, wonderware

I am new to wonderware InSQL historian.
I retrieve data for only one day, I have values sets to zero every time after incrementing for few values..

```
 0
 1
 2
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 0
```

[image]

I want to calculate the number of rows with values more than 0, 
at the moment I am using count function and value>0 in my query
but I would like to use, if any InSql retrieval option to count the number of values..

```
select count(value) FROM *****.Runtime.dbo.History
            WHERE TagName = 'TagA'
            AND DateTime >= '2016-06-14 06:00:00'
            AND Value > 0
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

There are no retrieval mode in Wonderware Historian that can be used in a straightforward manner to solve your problem. Your proposed solution is probably the best one but be aware that it will display an incorrect value in case of a disconnection and reconnection scenario.

In case of a disconnection a NULL value will be logged and at reconnect the same value will be logged again (e.g. 0, 1, 2, NULL, 2, 3, 0, 1) resulting in the same value being counted twice.

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for the reply.. I am using Counter retrieval mode for my above problem.. and I am getting the accurate results when i check